# Where clause on a SQL Server XML column filtering on attribute AND value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a 'Metadata' field in table 'Document' that has the following data:

```
<properties>
  <property name="someProp">xyz</property>
  <property name="reportId">55</property>
  <property name="someOtherProp">abc</property>
</properties>'
```

How can I write a query that returns records where a property element exists with a name of "reportId" and that "reportId" property element has a value of 55? Sometimes the "reportId" property node is the only one that exists, sometimes not, and it's not always in the above order so I can't query on absolute positions.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to extract the value. Use [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) instead.

```sql
select *
from Document
where Metadata.exist('/properties/property[@name="reportId" and . = 55]') = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, got it.  For reference:

```
select * from Document
where Metadata.value('(/properties/property[@name="reportId"])[1]', 'int') = 55
```